# 404 error using tomcat 6 for spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

The war file is working using tomcat 7, but not tomcat 6.

I want the war file working in tomcat 6, but I keep getting HTTP Status 404.

My env is: Java 6, Tomcat 6, Spring 4.0.0.

You can download code from: https://github.com/yizhaocs/springmvc4-angularjs-tomcat6-java6

Does anyone know the reason?

The following is my maven pom file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.websystique.springmvc</groupId>
<artifactId>Spring4MVCAngularJSExample</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>Spring4MVCAngularJSExample Maven Webapp</name>

<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- external dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java Servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- The JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL) is a collection of useful JSP tags which encapsulates core functionality common to many JSP applications. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>Spring4MVCAngularJSExample</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <finalName>Spring4MVCAngularJSExample</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: Did you check the log file for any exceptions? or are there any exceptions during tomcat 6 startup?

Comment: Hi nickspol, I just checked the log files. There is no error or exceptions in "localhost.2016-03-22.log" and "catalina.2016-03-22.log".

Comment: @nickspol    Here is my code: https://github.com/yizhaocs/springmvc4-angularjs-tomcat6-java6

Comment: you are accessing`http://localhost:tomcat_port/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample`  Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Servlets version 3.0, which [Tomcat 6 does not support](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

If running on Tomcat 7 is not an option, you must downgrade your web application to Servlets version 2.5, and write a web.xml file for your web app instead of configuring your web app in code.

Comment: thanks a lot, you are right! It's working after I change servlets version to 2.5 and rewrite java configuration to web.xml and [servletname]-servlet.xml